tabularray: Use `caption` package to format table caption while typesetting tables without caption or LOT entry
I am writing a longer document divided into \frontmatter and \mainmatter using the scrbook class. While both a table caption and a LOT entry should be generated for tables provided in the mainmatter, both items need be omitted/suppressed for tables given in the frontmatter (think e.g. list of abbreviations, list of symbols ...).
Furthermore, to have consistent caption formatting for tables, figures, listings etc., I decided to rely on the caption package.
Using the caption package to format the caption of tabularray tables as been elaborated in several places like:

How to auto-copy the formatting from \usepackage{caption} to the caption of tabularray?
Use caption style defined with caption package in tabularray's longtblr
Table captions continued

Similarily, creating tables without caption and LOT entry is described in multiple instances:

tabularray's manual (https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf, end of section 4.1):


If you write entry=none, tabularray package will not add an entry in List of Tables. Therefore
caption=text,entry=none is similar to \caption[]{text} in longtable.
If you write label=none, tabularray package will not step table counter, and set the caption-tag
and caption-sep elements (see below) to empty. Therefore caption=text,entry=none,label=none is
similar to \caption*{text} in longtable, except for the counter.


How do I omit the caption of a continued table on the second page using tabularray
Remove the table label within "longtblr"

While both approaches are working when used on their own (I might have missed some edge cases), I do not get it working in combination.
What am I missing? How can a use the caption package to format the captions of a tabularray table supporting both tables without captions and LOT entries (in the frontmatter) and "normal" tables (in the mainmatter) of my document?
MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    font={footnotesize, sf},
    labelfont={bf},
]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}

% remove continuation line at table footer
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}

% define table template with empty captions on first and continued table instances,
% remove continuation line in footer
\DeclareTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DeclareTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{nocaptemplate}{}

% use table template to define new theme
\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{First Chapter in Frontmatter}

This chapter contains a table without any caption, label or LOT entry:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{entry = none}
    \item \texttt{label = none}
\end{itemize}

Problem: (Empty) caption and LOT entry are provided, when using \texttt{caption} and \texttt{tblr-extras} packages for formatting. Uncomment corresponding lines in header to see that is it working without the these two packages.

\begin{longtblr}[
    entry = none,
    label = none,
    % apply theme to obtain table without caption on continued table
    theme = mytabletheme,
    ]{
        colspec={
            l
            X[l]
        },
        rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 0,
    }
    \toprule
    column 1 & column 2 \\
    \midrule
    a & b \\
    \pagebreak
    a & b \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter in Mainmatter}

This chapter contains a table with caption, label and LOT entry.

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {The first table with caption},
    entry = {The first table with caption},
    label = {tbl:first_table_with_caption},
    ]{
        colspec={
            l
            X[l]
        },
        rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 0,
    }
    \toprule
    column 1 & column 2 \\
    \midrule
    a & b \\
    \pagebreak
    a & b \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


You are missing templates for firsthead, middlehead and lasthead in your theme.
And, by the way, I cleaned up the code a bit. E.g., \DeclareTblrTemplate -> \DefTblrTemplate for consistency.
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    font={footnotesize, sf},
    labelfont={bf},
]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}

% remove continuation line at table footer
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}

% define table template with empty captions on first and continued table instances,
% remove continuation line in footer
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{nocaptemplate}{}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{nocaptemplate}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{nocaptemplate}{
  \UseTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}
}

% use table template to define new theme
\NewTblrTheme{mytabletheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption}{nocaptemplate}
  \SetTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{nocaptemplate}
  \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{nocaptemplate}
  \SetTblrTemplate{caption-lot}{empty}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{First Chapter in Frontmatter}

This chapter contains a table without any caption, label or LOT entry:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \texttt{entry = none}
    \item \texttt{label = none}
\end{itemize}

Problem: (Empty) caption and LOT entry are provided, when using \texttt{caption} and \texttt{tblr-extras} packages for formatting. Uncomment corresponding lines in header to see that is it working without the these two packages.

\begin{longtblr}[
    entry = none,
    label = none,
    % apply theme to obtain table without caption on continued table
    theme = mytabletheme,
    ]{
        colspec={
            l
            X[l]
        },
        rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 0,
    }
    \toprule
    column 1 & column 2 \\
    \midrule
    a & b \\
    \pagebreak
    a & b \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter in Mainmatter}

This chapter contains a table with caption, label and LOT entry.

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {The first table with caption},
    entry = {The first table with caption},
    label = {tbl:first_table_with_caption},
    ]{
        colspec={
            l
            X[l]
        },
        rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 0,
    }
    \toprule
    column 1 & column 2 \\
    \midrule
    a & b \\
    \pagebreak
    a & b \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}




